# Delete common objects in two vectors/get duplicate objects in a vector (NOT erase)

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

I am making a game using SDL 2. This game will have customizable controls. However, if one key is bound to more than one function/task, this key should be highlighted in all instances to inform the user that the key has been repeated. I am looking for *the easiest* way to find the duplicate keys.

My thoughts are to convert the vector into a set and back, to make it unique, and then remove all of the unique values from the original vector. My question then becomes, *Is there an easier way to remove the from a vector that it has in common with another vector than removing each object individually?* Like (where `a` and `b` are the vectors) `a.remove(b.begin(), b.end())`?

**OR**, is there an easier way to get the objects that are duplicated in a vector?

Just to clarify, I want to get `[a, f]` from `[d, e, a, a, g, f, c, f, f]`. I ***DO NOT*** want the vector of unique objects, `[a, c, d, e, f, g]`. I also know that I can do this by iterating through the vectors a few times, I just want *an easier* way, if there is one.

Let me know if you need any code (there isn't much to give), and thanks in advance!

Comment: You could always solve this by using *two* containers, one for the actual mappings, and another which keep track of the key binding count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting all the repeated elements of a vector is a costly operation (you would have to iterate for each vector element through all the rest of the vector) and won't be an "easy" way to do it (talking about iterations) but transforming into a set and back don't seem a good option.

The options I can think of:

1. Try to use a set (or map) from the beginning, those seem good options for your problem about controls, if you don't wan't them ordered (as set and map are), check unordered_map or unordered_set, which will allow you to store elements unordered without repetition
2. If you need a vector, a better option than checking all the vector is check each time an element is stored (won't be much better but at least cleaner)
3. Store a set of used elements with the vector, each time you insert any control in the vector, also insert in the set, this way you will easily check each time if the control has been assigned (you will consume more memory, but won't have to create a new set each time)

There may be other options, but I can't find the "perfect" way to solve this as it depends on how you need your structure